# What does it mean when the Monero daemon says "LMDB Mapsize increased"?

Tags: monerod, synchronization, lmdb

I had an old daemon open and it was giving me the various SYNCHRONIZED OK messages that I was used to. Suddenly it said "LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 13312MiB, New: 14336MiB". What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For performance reasons, LMDB asks the OS to preallocate its storage space in large chunks, instead of growing incrementally as new records are added. Periodically this space must be increased as the actual usage increases.

Comment: So this is a request for a larger footprint on the hard drive?

Comment: It's a request for more storage space. Whether you're using a hard drive or something else.